# Elements superposed using Android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following Android layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slideTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:padding="@dimen/px20"
        android:text="@string/login_message"
        android:textSize="@dimen/px25"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slideDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/px20"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/password"
        android:padding="@dimen/px20"
        android:text="@string/login_message_body"
        android:textSize="@dimen/px20" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/swipeMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But all the elements are positioned at the top of the screen one on top of the other, like if they didn't occupy any space.

That's not what what it seems to happen in the [*RelativeLayout* documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), where all elements are vertically positioned one below the other.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to use the id of the other components to align then properly.

For example the `TextView` with the id `@+id/slideDescription` should also have
`android:layout_below="@+id/slideTitle"` as one of the properties of the xml.

And the `TextView` with the id `@+id/swipeMessage` should also have
`android:layout_below="@+id/slideDescription"` as one of the properties of the xml.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are correct, I accepted this one because it's more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to place one view below another in RelativeLayout you have to use [layout_below](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below) property and set the ID of View you want to be above the specified one. But actually in order to place views vertically below each other it is more convenient to use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with orientation set to vertical

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had a LinearLayout but I switched to the RelativeLayout because I wanted to position one element at the bottom of the screen with *android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"*.

Comment: That's what the **relativity** of a RelativeLayout's children offers.

Answer (score 1):

layout_below is missed in the above xml code.I replaced the code with that please use that.

In Relative layout elemnets will be arranged relative to other elements in order to do this we should use id values of individual view elments

**android:layout_below="@id/slideTitle"  should be placed in description text view
 android:layout_below="@id/slideDescription" should be placed in message text view**

in order to get the output you desired please use the below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slideTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:padding="@dimen/px20"
    android:text="@string/login_message"
    android:textSize="@dimen/px25"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slideDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/slideTitle"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/px20"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/password"
    android:padding="@dimen/px20"
    android:text="@string/login_message_body"
    android:textSize="@dimen/px20" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/swipeMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/slideDescription"
    android:text="" />
```